# Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/client'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in react,
I try to run react application from an existing project from GitHub, when I used npm start command to run it, I got this error.

I need some help :)

package.json file

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGyv8.png)

Comment: react-dom/client works after react 18, your package.json shows react 16

Comment: I should update it ? I change  "react": "^16.13.0" to  "^18.0.0"

Comment: If the project you found is using "reactdom/client" then yes v18 mandatory. Your other packages seem new. If there isn't any compatability issue in rest of the code, you should.